# Extract a string of words between two specific words, but allow for a mismatches in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have the following string.

```
string =c("today is Oscar")
```

I want to extract everything between *today* and *Oscar* but allow for a maximum of two mismatches/typos in words *today* and *Oscar*.

The expected outcome, in this case, will be `is`, but there are strings that have another word between today and Oscar. Typos can occur in any letter in words *today* and *Oscar*.

I am currently having a look at the agrep package. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Hello @LDT, perhaps you can help us to understand your expected result (is it `" is "`?). I don't think it's hostility but please, if you could put what have you tried it will guide us to help you.

Comment: Do the first and third words change or are they always these two but with potential spelling errors?

Comment: Thank you Zoe for the question. Potentially spelling errors might occur in every letter. I would like to allow maximum two spelling errors per word

Comment: How big is your real use case. Because I can think of ways, but they will be computationally expensive.

Comment: Hello Adam, I am sure you would have thought of something cool as usual. I am dealing with up to 3*10^5 cases

Comment: Good point! It is a vector of strings with a potential collection of start and end flags

Comment: Yes yes the start and end flags are paired. I ll update definitely the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to extract from your vector the verbs (i.e., the middle substring) *iff* the words on the left and on the right of it are maximally 2 insertions/deletions etc. distant from the `"today \\w+ Oscar"`pattern.

If that premise is correct you can first subset your vector on those strings that meet that condition using `agrep` (or `agrepl`) and second capture the substring in the middle in a capturing group `(...)` and refer to it using backreference `\\1` in `sub`'s replacement argument:

```
sub("\\w+ (\\w+) \\w+", "\\1", string[agrepl("today \\w+ Oscar", string, max.distance = list(all = 2), ignore.case = T, fixed = F)])
[1] "IS"    "drive" "goes"
```

Note: the argument `all` specifies "maximal number/fraction of all transformations (insertions, deletions and substitutions)"; alternatively use: `insertions`, `deletions`, and `substitutions`.

Mock data:

```
string = c("today IS Oscar", "today drive car", "tody goes Oscar", "tomorrow was Oscar")
```

- `"today IS Oscar"` fully matches as `ignore.case = T` makes sure case doesn't matter
- `"today drive car"` is a fuzzy match as `car`is 2 steps away from `Oscar`
- `"tody goes Oscar"`is a fuzzy match as `tody` is 1 step away from `today`and
- `"tomorrow was Oscar"` is not a match at all as `tomorrow`is in excess of 2 steps distant from `today`

Comment: Dear Chris, It looks great. I ll check it once I arrive home. Thank you for your answer

Comment: I was thinking somewhat similar, but was worried about execution time on this type of thing. I was going the route of tokenizing each vector on the words, and then running that word vector into `stringdistmatrix(a, b, method = "lv")` against the "start flags" and "end flags". For each block of words from the vectors, extract the terms in between start and end flags. I may try later, but it seemed like it would take more time than I had at the second.

Comment: Thank you Chris for your answer. Thank you Adam for the comments. Unfortunately the hostility keeps going on and people want the answer to close. Its a pity because it can be useful to others. Thank you for your time. I appreciate